# How to fix "The server can not find the requested page" error with htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Intermittently I get the error 'The server can not find the requested page' when trying to view pages on my website. Generally pressing refresh resolves the issue.

I suspect this is caused by some of the rewrite rules in the htaccess file, but I can't see what is wrong.  The contents of the file is below:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sequences$ sequences.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings$ user-settings.php [L]
RewriteRule ^variables$ user-variables.php [L]
RewriteRule ^help/([^/\.]+)/?$ help/help.php?content=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^help$ help/help.php [L]
RewriteRule ^help/$ help/help.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$ terms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^trigger-webhook/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ trigger-webhook.php?k=$1&s=$2&t=$3 [L]
```

An example of a page which has returned the error is /help/conditions, but I have also experienced this from other pages. I'll come back with more examples as they happen.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Is the contents of the htaccess file correct?

Comment: Your .htaccess looks fine, have you checked your server error logs?

Comment: Try disabling MultiViews, it is often the culprit in situations where you have actual file names that partially match your “fake” URLs. If that doesn’t do it - then you can enable rewrite logging to find out what exactly is going on.

Comment: I've disabled Multiviews and will see how it goes over the next week. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A month on and I'm no longer seeing this issue. I believe the suggestion from @04FS resolved this.

I disabled multiviews using this line of code:

`Options -Multiviews`